# Is it possible to have 'global' UI in a Xamarin Shell project that displays on top of every other view?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I'm *super* new to Xamarin development, coming from a front-end background. I'm currently in the early days of creating a music-playing app (Targeting Android and iOS), and I'm wondering if it's possible to implement something like the Apple Music / Spotify / Overcast persistent 'Now playing' UI.

It'd be easy enough to just embed that into every page we want to display it in, but ideally it'd stay in place when navigating between views. I've had a dig around but haven't been able to find any working example of such a thing, only discussions where someone has figured that it's theoretically possible to do.

My UI brain is telling me that having the banner be persistent as opposed to embedded in every view would be ideal but if it's going to increase the complexity of the app by a significant margin I'd be happy to give it a miss for the time being.

Comment: Have you tried using Global Styles in Xamarin.Forms. Information can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/application

Comment: I’m aware of global styles but that’s not what I’m asking about. I’m asking about the ability to display UI that is persistent across multiple views, independent of the current view, not just the ability to style something that appears in multiple views.

Comment: You can use Custom Renderer to rewrite the entire ContentPage. Details can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/contentpage